# Questions about Python time_to_sleep?

Tags: python, time

When writing the code, the following code will be activated on time, saying it is stopped until the hour.
However, to operate the code on time, it takes more than 59 minutes to run the code must run the code.
Is there a way to make it work at 12pm by adjusting the minutes and hours instead of seconds in that code?

---

```
enter code here`current_time = time.time()
time_to_sleep = (60 - (current_time % 60))
time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sleep, you can pause until a defined time:

```
import pause
from datetime import datetime

pause.until(datetime(2022, 10, 25, 12))
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can do it like this:

```
import datetime
import time


while datetime.datetime(2022,10,25,10,28,0) > datetime.datetime.now():
   time.sleep(30)
    pass
print("it's time to act")
```

but @Tanner version seems to be more preferable

Comment: To be fair, I like yours too :)

Comment: this is a tight loop. it will burn CPU cycles needlessly, checking the condition a million times a second. put some small sleep in the loop, say a second or so.

Comment: @Christoph you're right

Comment: time. sleep(30)
does it mean that when 2022.10.25.10.28.00 is reached, it will be executed after 30 seconds? That is, is the execution statement executed at 2022.10.25.10.28.30?

Comment: You'd better use the second version with `pause.until`, this one is just worse analog. Yes, you're right, this code checks time every 30 second (check pause can be set to any needed time), in some condition it really can wait another 30 second after pointed date.